# helper view with haml and simple_form

Tags: haml, helper, simple-form

I tried to insert a **simple_form** helper into a **view helper** (sorry for the pun) and using it with the  **Haml::Helpers**, example:

```
def front_box_search_html(form_object)
    my_custom_wrapper() do
        non_haml do
            simple_form_for( form_object ||= Form::Search.new, :url => front_search_path ) do |f|
                haml_concat f.input :phrase
                haml_concat f.button :submit
            end
        end
    end
end
```

but this code is not rendered correctly: all html code appears (the various html tags wrapper, the inputs and the labels) but **without the**  tag, As you can see this is the result (testing with RSpec, but in the browser is the same thing):

```
Failure/Error: helper.capture_haml{ helper.front_box_search_html }.should have_xpath("/html/body/div[@*]/form")
expected following text to match xpath /html/body/div[@*]/form:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <body>
  <div class= "boxSearch box">
   <p class = "sum">search title</p>
   <div class = "row string optional">
    <label class = "string optional" for="form_search_phrase"> word</label>
    <input class="string optional" id="form_search_phrase" name="form_search[phrase]" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class = "row buttons last">
    <input class = "button" id="form_search_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="search">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

to be honest I have not fully understood how to use various methods of  Haml::Helpers,  about the documentation is poor.

---

my env: rails 3.0.7, haml 3.1.4, simple_form 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but the 'simple_form_for' helper also outputs html so I think it should be:

```
haml_concat simple_form_for( form_object ||= Form::Search.new, :url => front_search_path ) do |f|
  haml_concat f.input :phrase
  haml_concat f.button :submit
end
```